# CakePHP blank screen admin functions on remote server

Tags: cakephp

i have problems with "backend" on my page. On my localhost all works great (admin panel, add/edit articals, add/edit news, add/edit users), but on my remote server, when i request eg. add artical or edit artical i get only blank page no view, i use debug 2, and google google every every day night but nothing :(, anyone who can helps me, and tell me what is problem? thanky you so much

Comment: Do you have anything in your default layout file?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by having whitespace after a PHP close.

Go through any/all files that might be getting hit, and get rid of the ending close PHP tag all-together.  If it's a PHP file, there's no need to close it, and it's even good practice NOT to, as it keeps stuff like this from happening.

Comment: thank you, but nothing happens, i remove all closed tags but nothing.. ( i have combination php and html code) .. and i remove all code and inssert only some text ("323323dsdsdsd") but nothing happens only blank screen still..

Comment: @AnnaDino - my guess is there's still a file somewhere that has whitespace.  Every time someone has this issue (assuming debug is 2), it ends up being whitespace issue.  Controllers, components, helpers, models...etc etc - check them all.  If it's not it, I'm not sure what else to say, but - seems it always boils down to that one sneaky file with whitespace.

Comment: is this code cleared,ok?
and what meaning whitespace after a php close? i do this?

http://pastebin.com/0Bbi3qau

Comment: That's a View file and shouldn't matter - only php files are the issues w/ whitespace at the end of the file (after a close php tag)

Comment: thanks, i am made only controller and model php files
please see
controller: http://pastebin.com/F0RRXTwT
model:http://pastebin.com/mzLRTtGK

Comment: @AnnaDino - are you sure you have debug set to 2?

Comment: sincerely, i dont know what debug on 2 mening and what is debug,i only know in my core.php have line code : "Configure::write('debug', 2);" and how to use debug i what is debug i cant understand ;( please help me please

Comment: Ending close tag was the problem in my case, after hours of searching this answer saved the day

Comment: @Dave, removed end tag in php files but facing same problem. Link is http://cabsforyou.com/testing/admin